# Putting a form element on another line

Tags: css

I'm trying to set up my form so that the text input is on one side, and two buttons take up the rest of the side, one on top and the other on the bottom.

I've tried to use br, but this has not done anything. I'm also doing this on Angular 7.0 if it matters.

HTML

```
<form class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" placeholder="Add Todo">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
   <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn">
</form>
```

CSS

```
.form {
   display: flex;
}

.form input[type='text'] {
   flex: 10;
   padding: 5px;
   height: 40px;
}

.form input[type='submit'] {
   flex: 2;
   height: 20px;
   display: block;
}

.form input[type='reset'] {
   flex: 2;
   height: 20px;
   display: block;
}
```

Currently, all three are side by side, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywgty.png). I want the two buttons to be on top of each other.

Comment: Did you try giving both elements display: block?

Comment: Please write a minimal [Code Snippet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193323/how-to-enter-code-snippets-in-posts-on-stack-overflow) with your relevant HTML and CSS. You can do it, when you edit your question

Comment: Yes I did, sorry I'll also paste my CSS code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: block` to your `input` elements to have them occupy a new line.
You can also divide the elements into two columns by wrapping the desired elements in `<div>` classes (in this case of `.left` and `.right`), and floating them both to the `left`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.left, .right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.right input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" placeholder="Add Todo">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to check buttons height to keep them 1/2 of input, I’m suggesting flexbox in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change your markup, you can use `display: grid`.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'form topbutton' 'form bottombutton'
}

input[type="text"] {
  grid-area: form;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  grid-area: topbutton;
}

input[type="reset"] {
  grid-area: bottombutton;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" placeholder="Add Todo">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
   <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A more solid solution may use flexbox:

```css
div.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  /* you may add height if you need it */
  /* height: 125px; */
}
div.row > * {
  flex: 1 1 80%;
}
div.row > .buttons {
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div.row > .buttons > * {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" placeholder="Add Todo">
    
    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn">
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've never used Angular, but I usually use two br afterward with html and it works fine, alternatively you could use css to manually change the location of each element with style and margin (top,left,etc.). ie: like so:

```
 br example:
<form class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" placeholder="Add Todo"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"><br><br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn"><br><br>
</form>


  css example:
 <form class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<input style=margin-top:90px type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" placeholder="Add Todo"><br><br>
<input style=margin-top:100px type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"><br><br>
<input style=margin-top:110px type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn"><br><br>
</form>
```